# Average of even numbers divisible by 3 c++,I don't understand why the code is running wrong

Tags: c++

I need help finding the error in this code. It's supposed to find the average of the input numbers that are even and divisible by three.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void enterarray(int a[], int &n) { 
    cout << "please enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
}

double average(int a[100], int n)
{
    int t = 0, count;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if( a[i] % 2 == 0 && a[i] % 3 == 0) {
            t = t + a[i];
            count++;
        }
    return t * 1.0 / count;
}

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int n;
    enterarray(a, n);
    cout << average(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you format your code?

Comment: Please reformat the code, and add exactly what's wrong.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please read [the editing and formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) then [edit] your question to improve it (like formatting the code properly, and actually asking a question).

Comment: Well, I would use the old trick of summing all the numbers until 2 remain and if that is divisible by 3 then so was the original.. Add a test for even.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie How do you know the code is incomplete?

Comment: "Even number divisible by 3" is the same thing as "number divisible by 6".

Comment: You should initialize `count` to zero.

Comment: .... and also ensure that the input value of `n` is between `0` and `100`.   Accessing array elements out of bounds causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: maths >> loops. Sum of all integers up to n is `n*(n+1)/2`. Sum of integers divisible by 6 up to 6*n is `3*(n)(n+1)`

Comment: @BenedictvonHeyl: Why did you insert the text “I need help finding the error in this code. It's supposed to find the average of the input numbers that are not divisible by 2 or 3.”? I do not see that stated by OP in the original or in any edit or in any comment, nor is it consistent with the code, which uses only the number divisible by 2 and by 3, not those that are not divisible by 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that your `count` variable is uninitialized and

> any uninitialized local/block scope built in type variable has a garbage value.

using(accessing) which can lead to **undefined behavior**.

The **solution** would be to initialize `count` like:

```
int t = 0, count = 0;
```

**Problem 2**: Note also that before dividing `t` by `count` you should check that `count!=0`. That is, if `count` is zero you could simply return `0` instead of dividing by `0` as i have done in the below shown program.

The below shown program uses `std::vector` instead of array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
//the first argument is a vector of int passed by reference
void enterarray(std::vector<int> &a, int &n) { 
    cout<<"please enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    int elem;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        cin >> elem;
        a.emplace_back(elem);
    }
}
//no need to pass n because we can find the size of the vector using size() member function 
double average(const std::vector<int> &a) {
    int t=0, count = 0;//initialize count and t to 0
    for(const int &element: a){
        std::cout<<element<<std::endl;
        if( element % 2 == 0 && (element % 3 == 0)) {
            t = t + element;
            count++;
        }
    }
    //make sure you don't divide by zero
    return (count > 0 ?(t * 1.0) / count: 0);
}
int main() {
    //create a vector instead of an array 
    std::vector<int> a;
    
    int n = 0;
    enterarray(a, n);
    
    cout<<average(a);//no need to pass n
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

count needs to be initialized.

```
    int t=0, count=0;
```

n should be initialized in main.

```
int n = 0;
```

`enterarray(int a[], int &n)` could do with bounds checking n is less-equal to 100.

Comment: `int a[], int n` doesn't make much sense in C++. It's fragile and unsafe, and the language offers better alternatives.

Comment: Evg refers probably to gsl::span. Could you provide an explanation why n need to be initialized in main ?  The first action on n in enterarray is take the reference, then cin >> n; does it need to be initialized before ?

Comment: Actually n doesn't "need" to be initialized in main, just that I would. Edited